# How to calculate the velocity gradient at the wall normal to the wall (Boundary layers)?

Tags: aerodynamics

This problem is from "Fundamentals of aerodynamics" by John D. Anderson, Jr (Fifth edition, page 101):

Consider a flat plate at zero angle of attack in a hypersonic flow at Mach
10 at standard sea level conditions. At a point 0.5 m downstream from the
leading edge, the local shear stress at the wall is 282 N/m^2. The gas
temperature at the wall is equal to standard sea level temperature. At this
point, calculate the velocity gradient at the wall normal to the wall.

I already know: $\tau_w = \mu\left(\frac{dV}{dy}\right)_{y=0} = 282$
but how to get $\mu$ ??

Also I don’t know what this is for: “The gas temperature at the wall is equal to standard sea level temperature”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In page 72 you'll find the value of µ at **standard sea-level temperature**...

Comment: oh I got it, thanks